# showing array content wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new in wordpress and I confuse how to solve this.

```
$redeem = array(
  date('Ymd'),
  $_POST['value']
);

if ($point && is_array($point)) {
  $n = sizeof($point);
  $point[$n] = $redeem;
   }

  update_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'value', $point);
} else {
  update_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'value', $redeem );
}
```

This code work properly, it makes the data in my database become array. The problem is, how can I show the data from my database into my work page ?

```
a:3:{i:0;s:8:"20160421";i:1;s:3:"222";
```

This is the result of value in my database. I just want to show the value of "222".

Thanks

Comment: this is a serialized odject, so you want to use `unserialize()` function over that object: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: I dont know if it is my browser or not, but could you give me a reference in english, because it is in russian. Thanks

Comment: Yes, i've updated my comment with EN link

Comment: Could some of you give me the example of the code ? I am new and I dont know much about the syntax. Thanks

Comment: @MarkVullen, checkout my answer below with simple code. Try that and let me know if you need further help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WordPress, when you insert/update array data into user_meta or post_meta table, it will automatically saves data in serialized form, so you have to unserialize those data while fetching.

Below you can find simple conversation for array to serialized data and serialized data to array. You have to pass serialized data into `unserialize` function to fetch `222` value.

```
$arr = array("name"=>"milap","language"=>"php","cms"=>"WordPress");
$sd  = serialize($arr);
$res = unserialize($sd);
echo "<pre>";print_r($res);
```

The output of above code is,

```
Array
(
    [name] => milap
    [language] => php
    [cms] => WordPress
)
```

Comment: hey, I try that and I got this as the result:
Array
(
    [0] => 20160421
    [1] => 222
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20160421
            [1] => 101
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20160421
            [1] => 100
        )

Comment: Can you explain how to fetch the 222 value right after this ?

Comment: If you have variable `$val`, Just access element `$val[1]` to get `222` value from array.

Comment: I mean not just accessing the value but also to write it into my work page. I already try to echo it but it doesnt work. I tried: echo $res[1];

Comment: I am confused, please write down your output array.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => 20160421
    [1] => 222
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20160421
            [1] => 101
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20160421
            [1] => 500
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20160421
            [1] => 120
        )

)
That's all of the result, thank for helping

Comment: From your array, just try to access `$res[1]`, store it into variable and echo that variable. that's all.

Comment: I can help you in this chat room, http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109117/wordpress-professional-help

Comment: ouch, I am sorry. I dont have much reputation to chat there they said.

Comment: @MarkVullen, try to earn some rapution, so i can help you :)

Comment: @MarkVullen, also consider my answer to upvote & accept it if possible.

Comment: actually it is the correct answer I think. I just need more understanding about my code.

Comment: @MarkVullen, correct, try to go step by step, you will find solution.